# tikz - how can I differ from a capacitor positive and negative pins?

Tags: circuitikz

How can I use the positive and the negative pins from a capacitor as reference to connect another parts in `tikz`?

```
[pC, l=$C_{21}$, name=C21, -]
```

Is it possible also for the normal capacitors?

```
[C, l=$C_{20}$, name=C20, -]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable tex code what you have tried so far? Can you also add an sketch/screenshot of that what you want to get? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing (and wnating) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to draw only a symbol, use `path` command.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\path (0,0) to [C, l=$C_{21}$, name=C21](1,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This code produces follow output.

[image]

Now you can use the anchors of this symbol using it's name, like:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\path (0,0) to [C, l=$C_{21}$, name=C21](1,0);
\draw (C21.east)--++(45:1);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And using with some Ti*K*z:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\path (0,0) to [C, l=$C_{21}$, name=C21](1,0);

\node at (-2,0) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm, inner sep=0pt](circ2){1}; 
\node at (2,2) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm, inner sep=0pt](circ1){2}; 

\draw (C21.east)--(circ1.-90);
\draw (C21.west)--(circ2.0);
\draw (C21.east)--++ (0:1) to [R,l_=$R_1$](3,0);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Notice that instead of using a path of length 0, you can also use `\node[Cshape](myC) at (whatever)`. You lose the labels (which are bound to the path, and given a path of 0 length, they work a bit out of luck), but it could be useful sometime.